# Standard time of basic actions in production line

Tags: production-technology

We are making a model to review changes to our production process.
For the model we need estimations for standard movements (waking speed, picking something up, ...)

What are the standard time?

Comment: I can suggest 2 hours to wake - that is until I get my first coffee…

Comment: So, what are the times for your standard processes? You need all of those, individual and sub totals etc before you start to make changes.

Answer (score 1):

Standard Times are established time measurements used in Industrial Engineering to estimate how long humans take to do something.

These are built by breaking down an activity into its core components and applying (usually) pre-determined values for each.  Times are in Time Measurement Units (TMU's), which are defined as .036 seconds (27.77 TMU/sec).  BAck in the early 20th century, IE's studied everything and came up with standard times to reach, grasp, position, move, etc.  MTM and MOST are commonly used methods to put all this together.

Now, how to do it?  Hire an IE, every one of them will be familiar with this.